# Using PUNICODE_STRING with regex_match in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to use the PasswordFilter function, and need to get Password variable value, which is a PUNICODE_STRING, then use regex_match to match a password policy.

The problem is that regex_match cannot recognize the PUNICODE_STRING.

What can I do?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for [`UNICODE_STRING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380518%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?  And in case it isn't clear a `PUNICODE_STRING` is the same thing as a `UNICODE_STRING*`

Comment: I was able to do a regex_match with a wstring, but not with an UNICODE_STRING. Do you know if there is any difference?

Comment: You'll have to pass a pointer to the buffer, i.e. `UNICODE_STRING::Buffer`. Since you are using a pointer, `p->Buffer` returns a pointer to the stored sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings stored as a `LSA_UNICODE_STRING` (or its typedefs) might not be null-terminated so passing the `Buffer` pointer to a function that is expecting a null-terminated string (or a `std::wstring`) is not guaranteed to be safe.

Instead, convert it to a `std::wstring` using the `Length` field to specify the length of the string:

```
PUNICODE_STRING pStringIn; // this comes from somewhere
std::wstring strOut(pStringIn->Buffer, pStringIn->Length / sizeof(wchar_t));
```

You can then use `strOut.c_str()` or pass it directly to functions that accept a `std::wstring`.

Comment: Somehow in my haze I missed the warning about missing null terminators.  Thanks for catching my mistake.